# Transforming dataset to compute Paired Samples Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(Patient_ID = 1:4, Before = c(7L, 5L, 3L, 6L), 
    After = c(8L, 3L, 0L, 6L), Difference = c(1L, -2L, -3L, 0L
    ), Drug_1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Drug_2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to compare the `Difference` in scores (before vs. after) between people who take drug 1 and drug 2.

I tried this, but not sure if this is correct:

```
wilcox.test(Difference ~ Drug_1, data = dt, paired = TRUE)
```

I imagine that I would need to transform this to a long format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's ok, `Drug_1` clearly splits between `Drug_1` and `Drug_2`. You can compare with default S3 method.

```
all.equal(wilcox.test(Difference ~ Drug_1, data=dt, paired=TRUE)[c('statistic', 'p.value')],
          wilcox.test(dt$Difference[dt$Drug_2 == 1], dt$Difference[dt$Drug_1 == 1], paired=TRUE)[c('statistic', 'p.value')])
# [1] TRUE  ## Note: ties warnings removed
```